# Can we force value for user defined datatypes in simulator?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

Sorry, It may be very basic question. But I could not find any solution on and off the line. 
I am using vivado 2013.4 version for my tasks. Here is my code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.math_real.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

package my_package is
    type my_datatype is 
    record 
        n1 : real ;
        n2 : unsigned(31 downto 0);
        n3 : unsigned(31 downto 0);
        n4 : unsigned(31 downto 0);
        nE : integer;
    end record;
end my_package;

use work.my_package.all;

entity read_mydata is
     Port (a_in : inout my_datatype ; b_out : out my_datatype );
end read_mydata;

architecture Behavioral of read_mydata is
begin
    b_out <= (abs(a_in.n1), a_in.n2, a_in.n3, a_in.n4, abs(a_in.nE));  
end Behavioral;
```

The code has no visible error. My question is, how to force the input in the simulator? I tried forcing the a_in using comma and semicolon seperators. There was error. For example, In Tcl console,

```
 add_force {/read_file/a_in} -radix bin {2.5, 5, 4, 3, -2 0ns}
 ERROR: [#UNDEF] Time value 5, is not a valid number
```

Is this program synthesisable?

Comment: `I tried forcing the a_in using comma and semicolon seperators` please edit the question to state what *exactly* you tried. `It didnt work` - what *did* happen? If there was an error message, please include that.

Comment: @scary_jeff added. Thank you!

Comment: You could [ask Xilinx](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/bd-p/SIMANDVERIBD)

Comment: And check [this on the use of add_force](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/63921.html)

Comment: Just write a VHDL testbench instead of using force commands. (Oh and it looks OK for synthesis apart from the use of Real)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [UG835](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_4/ug835-vivado-tcl-commands.pdf) for Vivado 2013.4, your TCL command is not correct.  You cannot assign all fields in the record at once.  It seems that you changed the name of your package as well in the meantime because `read_file` is not mentioned in your original code.  Anyway, you can run the following:

```
add_force {/read_mydata/a_in.n1} -radix dec {2.5 0ns}
add_force {/read_mydata/a_in.n2} -radix dec {5 0ns}
add_force {/read_mydata/a_in.n3} -radix dec {4 0ns}
add_force {/read_mydata/a_in.n4} -radix dec {3 0ns}
add_force {/read_mydata/a_in.nE} -radix dec {-2 0ns}
```

I tried your code in Vivado 2017.1.  (I don't have 2013.4 at my disposal.)  In my version, you can also right-click on the signal in the "Name" column and select "Force Constant..."

Comment: While your solution appears valid you might elaborate why a composite value can't be used in a TCL command with *get_object -recursive* and *get_value*. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.3 Record types "A record type is a composite type, objects of which consist of named elements. The value of a record object is a composite value consisting of the values of its elements."" A composite value would have the form of an aggregate  here `(2.5, 5, 4, 3, -2)`. 9.3.3 "An aggregate is a basic operation (see 5.1) that combines one or more values into a composite value of a record or array type."

Comment: UG835 says that a single HDL object must be specified that can be of any of a few listed types. Records are not one of them in my interpretation.

Comment: Had trouble excerpting? "The specified <value> depends on the type of the <hdl_object>. HDL types include: "logic", floating point, VHDL enumerated, and VHDL integral." "Accepted values for VHDL integral types is a signed decimal integer in the range accepted by the type." *get_values* should have been telling for the named object a_in. *get_object -recursive* should have told you to use the unnamed objects (selected names of elements).

Comment: And what's funny is UG937 *Simulation Tutorial) shows an add_force for a std_logic_vector (sine, in sinegen.vhd) which isn't of one of the listed types.